# Sync Calender Between Gmail and Outlook.com

Tags: sync, gmail, calendar, outlook.com, shared-access

I have an Outlook.com account *(not the Desktop app)* which is my primary email/calendar, whereas my wife uses Gmail as her primary account, and we really would like a shared calendar we both can edit/manage. How can I achieve this?

- **Current setup:** 
   I have created a calendar in Gmail and subscribed to it from my Outlook.com account; however, this is a one-way solution so I cannot add/edit events to the calendar from my account

Is there any way to solve this so we have a single calendar which both can manage from Gmail and Outlook.com?

Comment: Google got rid of this ability for for accounts

Comment: I know, but there are many smart people on the interwebz.. I'm hoping someone has figured something out :)

Comment: Difficult to work around if Google actively blocks the standard that made it possible to do this unless you already had it working.

Comment: I know, but you never know what's out there. F.ex. Techmans answer might be a solution :)

Comment: The best way I've found to do this is via CompanionLink since nothing else I've found matches the functionality it offers. While I use CompanionLink Pro, you would only need need [CompanionLink for Google](https://www.companionlink.com/google/), and your Sync will look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/8mREU0b) _(choose the 14-day [trial](https://www.companionlink.com/downloads/download.php?product=CLG) option, and if you like it, buy the one-time license, not the subscription)_

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to do the same you can export the calendar from Outlook and import it to Gmail. I think this is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. They want to synchronize.